# React.js useCallback missing dependency warning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting this famous warning:
React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'dashboardActions'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

The thing is, if I include it then the program does not work.
I included the useCallback in order to avoid a similar warning but on the useEffect. Now I get it on the useCallback hook.
I was not able to find a solution to this particular case, though I understand there's plenty of info online, I guess there is so much I am confused where to look.

export const StuffTable = () => {
const [dashboardState, dashboardActions] = useDashboard();

```
const loadStuff = useCallback(async () => {
    
    try {
        ...
        dashboardActions.loadStuff(response.data);
    } catch (e) {
        ...
    }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    loadStuff();
}, [loadStuff]);


return (
    ...
)
```

}

Comment: dasboardActions should be a dependence in the useCallback

Comment: You can by the way just define load stuff in useEffect. See this explanation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

Comment: @JjagweDennis that's the issue, if I do that, the program does not work. I know that's what the warning says, but it's not the solution. I'll check declaring it in the useEffect. Thanks!

Comment: That did not work. Now what gives me the warning is the useEffect instead, and I can't add that dependency because things stop working that way. So I cannot declare "dashboardAction" within this component, it's a redux dispatcher, it's declared where it should be.

Comment: Can I see the implementation of dashboardActions in useDashboard? Is it memoized?

Comment: Sure thing, just basic redux stuff:

  case dashboardActionTypes.LOAD_STUFF:
   return { ...state, stuffData: payload };

 function loadStuff(payload) {
  dispatch({
   type: dashboardActionTypes.LOAD_STUFF,
   payload
  })
 }